# Неправильно обрабатывается список в итераторе

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции, итераторы

Привет, разбираюсь с итераторами. Возникала проблема: мне возвращается 2 раза элемент из списка '33', но почему? В next я поместил цикл, который должен перебрать список, но обрабатывает только нулевой элемент и все. Насколько я понимаю, for должен перебрать и отобразить: 33, 12. Но не работает как я хочу, где я допустил ошибку? Мне нужно, что бы он обработал только нулевой и первый элемент, в независимости сколько значений содержит лист

```
class Valuefilter(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.list_data = args
        self.num = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.num != 2:
            self.num += 1
            for x in self.list_data:
                return x
        else:
            raise StopIteration


args = [33, 12]
iter = Valuefilter(*args)
for i in iter:
print(i)
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
class ValueFilter:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.list_data = args
        self.num = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.num != 2:
            value = self.list_data[self.num]
            self.num += 1
            return value

        else:
            raise StopIteration


items = [33, 12, 22, 11]
iter = ValueFilter(*items)
for i in iter:
    print(i)
```

Результат:

```
33
12
```

Comment: value = self.list_data[self.num] Можете объяснить, как это работает, я не понял зачем нужно доставлять [self.num] Я понимаю, что так оно работает, но не могу понять логику работы

Comment: чтобы вернуть следующее значение из self.list_data по индексу self.num

Answer (score 0):

1) По тому что метод класса `Valuefilter`

```
def __next__(self):
    if self.num != 2:
        self.num += 1
        for x in self.list_data:
            return x  # <<< вот здесь
    else:
        raise StopIteration
```

прерывает выполнение как только встретит инструкцию `return`.

Как правило после возврата управления от функции к основной программе всё что находится ниже инструкции `def` этой функции 'забывается', конечно с учетом того, что у вас в методе(функции) используется объект с некоторым сохраненным состоянием (ваш экземпляр).

2) Вы всегда перебираете одну и туже последовательность `self.list_data`. Это просто список, Вам возвращается его первый элемент.